# JavaScript component conversion to TypeScript: What is the type of props

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api

Migrating VueJS project from JavaScript + Options API to TypeScript + Composition API, I have gradually found equivalents of most of the stuff. One thing that I'm struggling with is the `v-model` feature. I found a [good article on implementing it using Composition API](https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-3-data-down-events-up/), where author creates a composable function that can be reused in components that want to implement `v-model`. I'm trying to now write an equivalent function using TypeScript.

Here is the original JS code:

```
import { computed } from 'vue'
export function useModelWrapper(props, emit, name = 'modelValue') { 
  return computed({ 
    get: () => props[name], 
    set: (value) => emit(`update:${name}`, value) 
  })
}
```

My TS implementation looks like this:

```
import { computed, ComputedRef } from '@vue/composition-api'

export function useModelWrapper<T> (props: Record<string, unknown>, emit: (event: string, value: T) => void, name: 'modelValue') : ComputedRef {
  return computed({
    get: () => props[name],
    set: (value) => emit(`update:${name}`, <T>value)
  })
}
```

This compiles fine but Vue is not too happy about it. I get

> No overload matches this call

error if I use this function in a component.

My suspicion is that the type of `props` in the TS version is not correct, but I was not able to figure out what type I should use there. I have tried it with `Object`, `unknown` and `any`, but none of them allows me to do `props[name]` in the getter (`any` does but TS complains that I shouldn't use `any` as the type of `props`).

What am I doing wrong here?

### Edit

Here is the full error text:

```
{
    "resource": "../ProjectsDropdown.vue",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#6",
    "code": "2769",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(options: ComponentOptionsWithoutProps<unknown, unknown, Data, {}, {}>): VueProxy<unknown, unknown, Data, {}, {}>', gave the following error.
Type '{ modelValue: PropType<Project>; }' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
Overload 2 of 3, '(options: ComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<string, Data, Data, {}, {}, Readonly<{ [x: string]: any; }>>): VueProxy<Readonly<{ [x: string]: any; }>, Data, Data, {}, {}>', gave the following error.
Type '{ modelValue: PropType<Project>; }' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'modelValue' does not exist in type 'string[]'.
Overload 3 of 3, '(options: ComponentOptionsWithProps<ComponentPropsOptions<Data>, Data, Data, {}, {}, ({ [x: number]: string; } & { [iterator]?: IterableIterator<string> | undefined; ... 32 more ...; 
toLocaleString?: string | undefined; }) | ({} & { ...; })>): VueProxy<...>', gave the following error.
Type '{ modelValue: PropType<Project>; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentPropsOptions<Data> | undefined'.
  Types of property 'modelValue' are incompatible.
    Type 'PropType<Project>' is not assignable to type 'Prop<unknown, unknown> | null | undefined'.
      Type 'new (...args: never[]) => Project & object' is not assignable to type 'Prop<unknown, unknown> | null | undefined'.
        Type 'new (...args: never[]) => Project & object' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: string[]) => Function'.
          Types of parameters 'args' and 'args' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.",
    "source": "Vetur",
    "startLineNumber": 59,
    "startColumn": 16,
    "endLineNumber": 119,
    "endColumn": 3
}
```

### Edit 2

Here is how I'm using this function in a component:

```
<script lang='ts'>
export default defineComponent({
  ...
  import { useModelWrapper } from '../usemodelWrapper'
  props: {
    modelValue: Object as PropType<Project>
  },
  setup (props, { emit }) {
  return {
    selectedProject: useModelWrapper<Project>(props, emit, 'modelValue')
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: How this method is called?

Comment: @Eldar: `props` section has a property `modelValue: Object as PropType<Project>` and the object returned by `setup()` function has a member `selectedProject: useModelWrapper(props, emit, 'modelValue')`

Comment: I think the issue is `, name: 'modelValue') ` part. This is a type declaration not a default value assignment. Try with it `name = 'modelValue')`

Comment: @Eldar: Thanks. Tried that. Still get the same error.

Comment: Please, update the question with the code where you use it. It's the most important part because it causes the error. If you use it like shown in the comment, the problem is that you don't use a generic

Comment: @EstusFlask: Thanks for pointing out. For a second I thought that was it, but it isn't. I'm still getting the same error. Added usage example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing your own answer, I feel like this could be even stricter.

```
import { computed, WritableComputedRef } from '@vue/composition-api'

export function useModelWrapper<TProps, TKey extends keyof TProps> (
  props: TProps,
  emit: (event: string, value: TProps[TKey]) => void,
  name: TKey = 'modelValue' as TKey
) : WritableComputedRef<TProps[TKey]> {
  return computed<TProps[TKey]>({
    get: () => props[name],
    set: (value: TProps[TKey]) => emit('input', value)
  })
}
```

I haven't tested it with Vue specifically but that function should restrict which key you can pass it as third argument and correctly infer the return type depending on which `name` was passed instead of a union of all values of `props`.

Comment: Yep. This works and infers types correctly. I'll add missing imports for sake of completeness and accept it as answer.

Comment: For Vue3 where do I get `WritableComputedRef` from? `import { WritableComputedRef } from "vue-demi";` ? thanks! Also it should be ``update:${name}`` IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Just in case it helps someone down the road, it turned out that I was using wrong version of `PropType` in the component to define my `v-model` prop. The real `PropType` class should be imported like this:

```
import { PropType } from '@vue/composition-api'
```

and not:

```
import Vue, { PropType } from 'vue'
```

### Edit

If it helps anyone, here is how I finally implemented a strongly-typed `v-model` using Composition API and TypeScript:

```
import { computed, WritableComputedRef } from '@vue/composition-api'

export interface IIndexable<T> { [key: string]: T }

export function useModelWrapper<T> (props: IIndexable<T>, emit: (event: string, value: T) => void, name = 'modelValue') : WritableComputedRef<T> {
  return computed<T>({
    get: () => props[name] as T,
    set: (value: T) => emit('input', value as T)
  })
}
```

You can then import it in any component like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ProjectsDropdown',
  props: {
    value: Object as PropType<Project>
  },
  setup (props, { emit }) {
    const selectedProject = useModelWrapper<Project>(props, emit, 'value')

    return { selectedProject }
  }
}
```

and bind it to whatever you want to bind in your component's template.

Please note that this works in Vue 2.x. For Vue 3, you'll want to change the name of `value` prop to `modelValue` and `emit('input', value as T)` with `emit('update:modelValue', value)` in the above code.

### Edit 2

See @emeraldsanto's answer below. It provides an even better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of @emeraldsanto's answer but the type inferences are  the Vue 3 component emit strings

```js
export function useModelWrapper<TProps extends Record<string, unknown> | { modelValue: unknown },
                                TKey extends keyof TProps & string = 'modelValue',
                                TEmit extends (event: `update:${TKey}`, value: TProps[TKey]) => void = (event: `update:${TKey}`, value: TProps[TKey]) => void > (
  props: TProps,
  emit: TEmit,
  name: TKey = 'modelValue' as TKey
) : WritableComputedRef<TProps[TKey]> {
  return computed<TProps[TKey]>({
    get: () => props[name],
    set: (value: TProps[TKey]) => emit(`update:${name}` as `update:${TKey}`, value)
  })
}
```

use like

```js
const props = defineProps<{
  modelValue: string
  foo?: number
}> ()

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'update:modelValue', id: string): void
  (e: 'update:foo', value: number | undefined): void
}> ()
const value = useModelWrapper(props, emit)
const fooValue = useModelWrapper(props, emit, 'foo')
```